# How to create CPaneDialog inside dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c++, dll, mfc

I have a DLL with MFC (statically linked) and a main application written in MFC.

I created a `CPaneDialog` and a `CDialog` inside the DLL, but I can't call the `CPaneDialog::Create` function inside the DLL because I don't have the pointer to the parentWnd. I also can't call `CPaneDialog::Create` inside the main MFC app because it lacks the dialog resource.

How can this be done?

**Update**

As Dan suggested, I am now calling the create function with a pointer passed to the DLL:

Code inside the DLL:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void init_toolbox_gui(void *ptr) {

  AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());

  CPaneDialog *_gui = new CPaneDialog;
  CWnd *_ptr = (CWnd*)ptr;

  _gui->Create(_T("DialogBar"), _ptr, TRUE, (IDD_DIALOG1),
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    154980);

}
```

This is called as follows (main app, class derived from `CWinAppEx`):

```
(...)
ToolboxInitFunc func = (ToolboxInitFunc)GetProcAddress(dll_instance, "init_toolbox_gui");

func(m_pMainWnd);
(...)
```

This does not work and creates assertion failures. What could be wrong?

**Update 2**

Now I am passing the main window `HWND` as follows:

```
ToolboxInitFunc func = (ToolboxInitFunc)GetProcAddress(dll, "init_toolbox_gui");

    func(m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
```

but I get the following failed assertion:

```
ENSURE(m_pDockManager != NULL);
```

This is the call stack

```
toolbox-3d.dll!CMFCDragFrameImpl::Init(CWnd * pDraggedWnd) Line 106 C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CPane::CreateEx(unsigned long dwStyleEx, const wchar_t * lpszClassName, unsigned long dwStyle, const tagRECT & rect, CWnd * pParentWnd, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle, CCreateContext * pContext) Line 177   C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CDockablePane::CreateEx(unsigned long dwStyleEx, const wchar_t * lpszCaption, CWnd * pParentWnd, const tagRECT & rect, int bHasGripper, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwStyle, unsigned long dwTabbedStyle, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle, CCreateContext * pContext) Line 175   C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CDockablePane::Create(const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, CWnd * pParentWnd, CSize sizeDefault, int bHasGripper, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwStyle, unsigned long dwTabbedStyle, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle) Line 148 C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CPaneDialog::Create(const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, CWnd * pParentWnd, int bHasGripper, const wchar_t * lpszTemplateName, unsigned int nStyle, unsigned int nID, unsigned long dwTabbedStyle, unsigned long dwControlBarStyle) Line 48   C++
toolbox-3d.dll!CPaneDialog::Create(const wchar_t * lpszWindowName, CWnd * pParentWnd, int bHasGripper, unsigned int nIDTemplate, unsigned int nStyle, unsigned int nID) Line 42 C++
toolbox-3d.dll!init_toolbox_gui(HWND__ * ptr) Line 45   C++
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass NULL as the parent window to a constructor of an MFC dialog, or to CPaneDialog::Create().  In fact, if you look up [CDialog::Create()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd.aspx), the CWnd* pParentWnd parameter is optional and defaults to NULL, and the doc states, "If it is NULL, the dialog object's parent window is set to the main application window."

But you probably want to have a global "C" function exported from the DLL, which takes the HWND of the parent window as a parameter, then calls [CWnd::FromHandle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e547yfza.aspx) with the HWND passed in and uses that as the parent CWnd in the call to CPaneDialog::Create().  The exported function should start with [AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9d5yh5.aspx) in order to load resources from the DLL properly.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I just realized that I lack more knowledge on this topic. Is there an example with `CPaneDialog` I can use? (I noticed there are some examples from something called MFC Feature Pack from Visual Studio 2008 but I can't find it. I use Visual Studio 2013 btw)

Comment: I tried doing that but i still get assertion failed. Check the update to see the code

Comment: I said to export a global function declared with extern "C", not a C++ class member function.

Comment: It's hard for me to diagnose what's wrong with your code without seeing all of it.  What exactly did you try?  Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Also, your question keeps changing, and is a moving target.  What happened to the part where I said that your exported function should "take the HWND of the parent window as a parameter, then calls CWnd::FromHandle() with the HWND passed in."  You can't use the same CWnd object in the program and the DLL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75878/discussion-between-manatttta-and-dan-korn).

Comment: How would I change that in the code I showed you? i.e. instead of m_pMainWnd what would I pass to the exported function?

Comment: I am now passing the m_pMainWnd HWND and I still get that assertion failed. What could be wrong?